# firebase js sdk query snapshot return null or error

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using firebase sdk I successfully login a user but later I can't query any data from the realtime database.
Chrome console says that snapshot.val() is null or it fires an error in firebase-database.min.js.
I tried many sort of querys and path format in ref value (from official doc and forums).
When I try to console.log the snapshot, it returns a firebase object. Adding .val() returns null. But I have data on db.

I have also tried .once or await async functions but it gives me same result.

I use firebase js sdk from cdn (v8): https://cdnjs.com/libraries/firebase/8.10.0

Links to code and errors screnshots: *removed*

Link to lite version project: *removed*

Firebase injection and init:

```
<!-- index.html -->

<script src="../lib/jquery_360/jquery360.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/bootstrap_5/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="../lib/firebase/firebase.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="../lib/firebase/firebase-app.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../lib/firebase/firebase-auth.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/firebase/firebase-database.min.js"></script>    

<script src="../script/modal.js"></script>
<script src="../script/utility.js"></script>

<script src="../script/customer.js"></script>

<title>customer</title>

// index.js - jquery onload function

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    // keys here...
});

auth = firebase.auth(); 
db = firebase.database(); 

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        var uid = user.uid;
        console.log('user logged in!');     
        
        $('#login_popup').modal('hide');
        Clear_Popup_Message('login_popup_msg_box', null); 
    
        GetAllData();         
    } else {
        console.log('user not logged in!');
    }
  });

// GetAllData()

db.ref('menus').orderByChild('list_order').on('value', (snapshot) => {
            prj.configs.menu = snapshot.val();  
});
```

[image: firebase realtime db]

[image: query error]

[image: rules]

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem. Please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code, data, and error messages that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Linking to another site where these artifacts may exist is not good enough here on Stack Overflow, as such links tend to rot over time - and we're trying to build a knowledge base.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the advice, i updated the post.

Comment: Thanks for that    I still don't see where in the code you shared that error message comes from though. This code should never raise that error as far as I can see: `db.ref('menus').orderByChild('list_order').on('value', (snapshot) => {
            prj.configs.menu = snapshot.val();  
});`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen indeed, the code is simple but the error doesn't help too much unfortunatly. I am using V8 firebase js sdk from that CDN. Are there other source available by any chance? Maybe libraries are the problem but i can't find other cdn anywhere. I can't use modular v9 at the moment.

Comment: v8 works just as well too, so that's not the issue. But without seeing an minimal-but-complete repro it's hard to say what's going on. Can you otherwise maybe set up a reproduction on a site like jsbin or stackblitz, so we can have a look it? So not a copy  of your project, but a minimal repro that we can actually run right there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have uploaded my lite version project into jsbin with firebase key. This way the user is logged and it's possible to see the error I get afterwards doing a select query. I don't know if it's safe but in case I changed firebase keys/users permission to "Viewer" (It was Editor). It should grant read-only rule.

Comment: Thanks! I share jsbin links to one of my oldest projects all the time. As long as you secure what folks can do to the database through security rules, there is no more concern then by including the same configuration data in the app itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is wrong with the libraries on Cloud Flare, but if I change your imports from

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/8.10.0/firebase-app.min.js" integrity="sha512-XNRpfd3CxEDrXcXWvht51k3l8G5cZhcY0kehFjUohBhgRDCozbdSaGz3w96WlDxAgiNZndKnpn1+4532FS3p3w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/8.10.0/firebase-auth.min.js" integrity="sha512-GAEvFso2oksY5JFkHlrfLhZgAV6aL48qxnbxPnbKnNLeG/XsU/c0lh/g9gocZ2RtbRx6VDTqspPEy9ixWvbfzw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/8.10.0/firebase-database.min.js" integrity="sha512-XDKFSZOhFNmwmx69Xr0j3zmePQ3NoSgpzZPr49P6oV7ME5ZhEXUqu+KUA0vQtof87P6IX+ycg4PmSms/EF8/pw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Everything suddenly works without errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved the issue in my local project too. I saw those gstatic cdn around but I couldn't find them. Are they available somewhere in official firebase doc?